# Prove $|x - x_0|<\delta_1\implies<|f(x)-L|<\epsilon/2$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta_2<\delta_1 \implies |f(x)-G| <\epsilon/2$ together imply $|G-L| < \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Consider the following results from two limits:

$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta_1, \delta_2:$

$0<|x-x_0|<\delta_1 \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon/2$

$0<|x-x_0|<\delta_2 <\delta_1 \implies |f(x) - G| < \epsilon/2$

$\therefore\epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2=\epsilon>|L-f(x)|+|f(x)-G|$

I would like to say $\epsilon > |L-G|$ using the triangle inequality, but I'm having the following problem: there are actually two $f(x)$ here, one whose domain is bound by $\delta_1$, and another whose domain is bound by $\delta_2$ < $\delta_1$. Since both are bound by $\delta_1$, the two symbols *could* be equal, but they are not necessarily so, and therefore reducing the expression using the triangle inequality $|a-c| \leq |a-b| + |b-c|$ would be incorrect. Is there a way to account for this, and still be able to solve the problem algebraically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\delta_2 < \delta_1$. For $x$ satisfying $$|x-x_0|< \delta_2,$$ both $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon/2$ and $|f(x)-G|<\epsilon/2$ hold, so you may apply the triangle inequality as you have. You don't need to keep around the larger bound $\delta_1$; you can effectively replace it with the smaller $\delta_2$.

For more complicated problems, one often takes the final $\delta$ to be the minimum of several other ones; for example, in this problem you are taking $\delta := \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$.

Comment: thanks for the help!